# How to disable linkbutton or hide linkbutton with JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have code like this:

```
 function rdLoanChecked() {

            var isCheckedInstallment = $find("<%= rdMonthlyInstallment.ClientID %>").get_checked();
            var isCheckedLoanAmount = $find("<%= rdLoanAmount.ClientID %>").get_checked();

            if (isCheckedLoanAmount) {
               
                document.getElementById('<%= btRecalculateByLoan.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('<%= btCalculateByInstallment.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('<%= btRecalculateByInstallment.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('<%= btnext.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('<%= btCalculateByLoan.ClientID %>').style.display = "inline";
             
            }
            else if (isCheckedInstallment) {
                
                document.getElementById('<%= btRecalculateByLoan.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('<%= btCalculateByInstallment.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('<%= btRecalculateByInstallment.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('<%= btnext.ClientID %>').style.display = "inline";
                document.getElementById('<%= btCalculateByLoan.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
            }
```

```
<td width="5%" style="vertical-align: middle;">
  <telerik:RadButton ID="rdLoanAmount" runat="server" ButtonType="ToggleButton" Text=""
   OnClientCheckedChanged="rdLoanChecked" CssClass="rdLoanAmount" 
   ToggleType="Radio" GroupName="rdCalculationBy" BorderStyle="None">
                        </telerik:RadButton>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
   <cc1:LocalizedLabel ID="lblLoanAmount" runat="server" Key="lblLoanAmount"></cc1:LocalizedLabel>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;" width="5%">
   <telerik:RadButton ID="rdMonthlyInstallment" runat="server" ButtonType="ToggleButton"
   OnClientCheckedChanged="rdLoanChecked" CssClass="rdMonthlyInstallment" 
   Text="" ToggleType="Radio" GroupName="rdCalculationBy" BorderStyle="None">
                        </telerik:RadButton>
</td>
```

I need hide or display some linkbutton with condition radiobutton (in this case radiobutton `radbutton telerik`).

This code not work.

Comment: Could you post some of your markup?

Comment: Thanks. It's my wrong I was try and work. thanks. All property link button must set visible to true for going to control.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of you "$find(...)" it seems like you're trying to use jQuery? If so, change the code of the variable declarations as follows:

```
var isCheckedInstallment = $("#<%= rdMonthlyInstallment.ClientID %>").is(":checked"); 
var isCheckedLoanAmount = $("#<%= rdLoanAmount.ClientID %>").is(":checked");
```

You need to tell the jQuery selector whether you are looking for an element type `$("element")`, element ID `$("#element")` or element CSS class `$(".element")`. Your variable declaration assumed you are looking for an element TYPE (i.e. a tag of type "`<%= rdMonthlyInstallment.ClientID %>`"), which is incorrect. You should be looking for an element ID.

Comment: $find() is the Telerik selector

Comment: ".get_checked();" this condition work. that's telerik function.

Comment: Didn't know that! I haven't worked with Telerik controls yet... The original question didn't have the Telerik markup in. Ah well, feel free to ignore the answer then.

Comment: Thanks. It's my wrong I was try and work. thanks.
All property link button must set visible to true for going to control.

Answer (score 0):

I think a problem is that you always set display = "none" to the btRecalculateByLoan, btCalculateByInstallment and btRecalculateByInstallment

Comment: I'm was remove them and still not happend

Comment: have you checked if isCheckedLoanAmount and isCheckedInstallment have the right values? Place an alert inside the "if" and the "else" to see if you go through the right code